# How do I do individual alt tags in .php files controlled by a template?

Tags: php, alt

I have 5000 images on individual php files. Like this one: -
http://www.tonyhowell.co.uk/v/5438.php

I can't add **alt="Oak Tree"** because php doesn't like the "speech" marks. I can't add them to the php template as each template controls hundreds of different images.

How do I add the alt tags to each .php file please?

Comment: `alt='Oak Tree'` (single quotes)? You didnt provide any code, so i asume you print out HTML Markup inside double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the characters or use single quotes for strings.

```
echo '<img src="3" alt="Something" />';
```

Or

```
echo "<img src=\"3\" alt\"Something\" />";
```

Comment: Personally I prefer to write / see the first code without `\"`.

Answer (score -1):

Escape them

```
$altTag = "alt=\"Oak Tree\"";
```

Or if you want it easier, you can simply use `'`

```
$altTag = "alt='Oak Tree'";
```

Every browser will translate those into the correct ones. Yes, even IE 7.

Comment: ```$altTag = "alt='Oak Tree'";``` It's not the best way to write it.
```$altTag = 'alt="Oak Tree"';``` is better (xhtml valid) and better to use `'` instead of `"` in PHP.

Comment: @ChoiZ It doesn't really matter which quotation marks you use for the variable enclosing. The only difference is if you place a variable name inside the double quotationmarks, it will be parsed, while it will be printed as it is in the single quotationmarks. In this case, it doesn't matter at all what you use.

Comment: @Y U NO WORK yes and no, for me you don't do this at all. If you rewrite code later and add variable, you don't have to change your quotes but just have to concat your variable. In your code you have to concat variable and change quotes (less efficient).

Comment: Oh, I still have a problem. My code is: -    $photoPath = "/new/8/Sea-Front-Weston-Super-Mare_DSC0041.jpg"     but if I add the alt the image doesn't appear.   $photoPath = "/new/8/Sea-Front-Weston-Super-Mare_DSC0041.jpg alt='Sea Front, Weston Beach'";  If I close off the image with speech marks      $photoPath = "/new/8/Sea-Front-Weston-Super-Mare_DSC0041.jpg" alt='Sea Front, Weston Beach'"; it still doesn't work -sorry but I'm not understanding what I've done wrong! Also, I don't understand what 'Indent four spaces' means to put the code in a grey box! I tried spacebar

Comment: Think I've just realised why it may not work. This code is from the template controlling the file with the $photoPath in post above    <img src="<?php echo $photoPath; ?>" alt="&lt; Back" id="Baba"></a>    - should I create an echo for the alt somehow?